# Silverstripe 3.1 Validation error on csv bulk upload

Tags: image, csv, silverstripe, validationerror

i am trying to get a csvbulkupload to work.

but there seems to be a problem with copying the files: [Error] Uncaught Exception: Cannot move /home/www/22/42/cwwebde123/art-/assets/new-produktbild-image to /home/www/22/42/cwwebde123/art-/assets/NEW-HAVEN-08578078-G55.jpg - /home/www/22/42/cwwebde123/art-/assets/new-produktbild-image doesn't exist

/home/www/22/42/cwwebde123/art-/framework/filesystem/File.php:532

```
<?php
class ProdukteCsvBulkLoader extends CsvBulkLoader {
public $columnMap = array(
'Marke'     =>  'Marke.Title',
'Leisten'       =>  'Leisten',
'Artikelnr'     =>  'Artikelnummer',
'Artikelname'   =>  'Artikelname',
'Saisoncode'    =>  'Saison',   
'Saionname'     =>  'Saionname',    
'Geschlechtcode'    =>  'Geschlecht',
'Geschlechtname'    =>  'Geschlechtname',
'Farbcode'      =>  'Farbcode',
'Farbname'      =>  'Farbname',
'Artikelnrzusammengefasst'      =>  'Artikelnummerzusammengefasst',
'Beschreibungdeutsch'           =>  'BeschreibungDE',
'Beschreibungenglisch'          =>  'BeschreibungEN',
'Artikelnrzusammengefasst'      =>  'Produktbild.Name'
);


public $duplicateChecks = array(
'Artikelnr' => 'Artikelnummer'
);

public $relationCallbacks = array(
'Marke.Title' => array(
'relationname' => 'Marke',
'callback' => 'getMarkeByTitle'
),
'Produktbild.Name' => array(
'relationname' => 'Produktbild',
'callback' => 'imageByName'
)
);


public static function getMarkeByTitle($obj, $val, $record) {
$marke = Marke::get()->filter('Title', $val)->First();
return $marke;
}

static function imageByName($obj, $val, $record){
$filename = Convert::raw2sql($val);
$filename = "assets/Produktbilder/".$val;
if($filename && $image = DataObject::get_one('Image',"\"Filename\" LIKE '%$filename%'")){ 
if($image->ID && $image->ClassName = 'Image'){
$image->ClassName = 'Produktbild_Image';
$image->Filename = $filename;
echo $image->Filename; die();
return $image; 
}
}
return null;
}

}
?>
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: There seems to be a problem with File->onAfterWrite(). I get the following error now:

[Error] Uncaught Exception: Cannot move 
/home/www/22/cwwebde822/art/assets/NEW-HAVEN-08578076-G69.jpg to /home/www/22/cwwebde822/art/assets/NEW-HAVEN-08578076-G29.jpg - /home/www/22/cwwebde822/art/assets/NEW-HAVEN-08578076-G69.jpg doesn't exist
/home/www/22/cwwebde822/art/framework/filesystem/File.php:532 

A var_dump after the $image->write(); returns the following:

["Filename"]=>
    string(47) "assets/Produktbilder/NEW-HAVEN-08578078-G55.jpg"

Comment: i dont know why, but in field Filename it is assets/NEW-HAVEN-08578076-G29.jpg instead of assets/Produktbilder/NEW-HAVEN-08578076-G29.jpg   How can i set the correct path? In $image->Filename it is still correct?

Comment: now i get a File->updateFilesystem() error.
[Error] Uncaught Exception: Cannot move assets/new-produktbild-image to assets/NEW-HAVEN-08578078-G55.jpg - assets/new-produktbild-image doesn't exist
framework/filesystem/File.php:532